# ionic angularjs function is undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I know this same question has been asked many times before, but no solution worked for me. And I already have spent many hours on it.

In my case I am simply replacing a text with with an html element and on onclick event I want to call an event or a function defined in the same class.

```
var linkToReplace = '<a onclick="this.events.publish(\'issue:display\')">'+issueKey+'</a>';
```

Error is given below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'publish' of undefined.
```

it works for "alert(\'hello\')", but all other functions got undefined.

Thanks in advance!